# How to use Picker with data model

Tags: swiftui, picker

I am trying to make a year selector, with information that comes from an array, but whenever I select an option the selector always returns automatically to the first position, how could I save the selected year in my $ i.anio?

Thank you
[image]

```
//---------------MODEL-----------------
struct SysNoAntpatologicosModel {
    var anio: Int
    var descripcion: String
    var idantnopat: Int
    var nombre: String
    var presente: Bool
}
//-------------ARRAY----------------
[{
    anio = 2001;
    descripcion = "test1";
    idantnopat = 38;
    nombre = Accidente;
    presente = 0;
},
{
    anio = 2002;
    descripcion = "test2";
    idantnopat = 42;
    nombre = Inmunizacion;
    presente = 0;
}
]

@State var dataSys : [SysNoAntpatologicosModel] = []

 ForEach($dataSys, id: \.idantnopat) { $i in
     HStack{
            Picker("", selection: $i.anio) {
                   ForEach(2000...2021, id: \.self) {
                           Text($0)
                   }
            }
            .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
            .onChange(of: i.anio) { tag in
               print("year: \(tag)")
            }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is the outer ForEach, do you have a list of pickers in your view?

Comment: You are mixing types wildly here, the picker contains Int values but for the data you presented anio is a String but in the struct anio is a Date. Very confusing.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'll change the data types to integer, I'll try again

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It worked for me changing all the type of data to integer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your edits, you're very close -- you just need to add `""` around the `Text` input so that it will compile:

```
struct SysNoAntpatologicosModel {
    var anio: Int
    var descripcion: String
    var idantnopat: Int
    var nombre: String
    var presente: Bool
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var dataSys : [SysNoAntpatologicosModel] =
        [.init(anio: 2001, descripcion: "test1", idantnopat: 38, nombre: "Accidente", presente: false),
         .init(anio: 2002, descripcion: "test2", idantnopat: 42, nombre: "Inmunizacion", presente: false),
        ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($dataSys, id: \.idantnopat) { $i in
            HStack{
                Picker("", selection: $i.anio) {
                    ForEach(2000...2021, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)") //<-- Here
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
                .onChange(of: i.anio) { tag in
                    print("year: \(tag)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me changing all the type of data to integer, thanks!